# Persisting an aggregate individually or as a whole over an API

Tags: api-design

Let's say I'm building a trivia game where users can create games with exactly 5 questions and 4 options (games, questions & options have their own database tables) for each question and assume I'm using a front-end MVC and a backend API.

I've always had this dilemma as to how the API should be designed.

Should I:

1. have individual APIs for games, questions, and options
2. keep the game as an aggregate of game details, questions, and options and let the backend receive this as a whole

The disadvantage of 1. is that when I'm creating a new game I'll need to make ton of API calls to setup all questions of the game and their options. However, when updating the game, or any of it's questions, it's a simple update API call for each resource we're dealing with.

The advantage of 2. is that the initial setup is a single API call. The disadvantage becomes apparent when updating the database: the backend has to iterate through *all* the questions and options again, even if it's only a single question that needs to be updated.

Am I missing any other aspect of these two design decisions?

Answer (score 2):

What you're claiming is that you have to either design your system to be configured only with many API calls that make small changes or configure it all at once with one big change. The truth is you can do both.

In fact the [convention over configuration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) idea says you should start with one big change to use as your default and make small changes to customize.